# SearchView Alway Null in CustomRenderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a search view in a custom renderer but it is always returning null I have tried several different approaches but so far same result. Right now I have settled on this because it at least is not throwing any other errors.

My Layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <SearchView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mapSearch"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
        class="Android.Widget.SearchView"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In OnElementChangedMethod

```cs
_activity = this.Context as Activity;
_searchView = (SearchView) _activity.FindViewById(Resource.Id.mapSearch);
SetupSearchView();
```

SetupSearchView Method

```cs
public void SetupSearchView()
{
    if (_searchView != null)
    {
        _searchView.QueryTextSubmit += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Query);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your mentioning the above works, so where is your approach that does not work that you've tried?  If you package up a small demo I will take a look.  My contact details are on my Profile.

Comment: The above for me doesn't work I will try and get a demo together this might be because it is also inside of a maprenderer

Answer (score 0):

If this is following your **PageRenderer** approach from previous questions, then perhaps the **OnElementChanged** is firing before the **Layout** has been **inflated**?, giving the **_searchView** a **null** as it can't be found at that point?

There may be a better handler to put this initialization logic but I haven't done anything on **Xamarin.Forms** **PageRenderers** at present.

Perhaps try finding the **SearchView** control, just **prior** to **executing a search**, should you **not** already have a reference from a previous search?

So something like:-

```
public void DoSearch()
{
    if (_searchView==null)
    {
        _activity = this.Context as Activity;
        _searchView = (SearchView) _activity.FindViewById(Resource.Id.mapSearch);
        SetupSearchView(); 
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then at least that will confirm whether or not it has anything to do with getting references too early in the **OnElementChanged** event handler?, indicating there is a *better* method to put this in?

Comment: How would I bind the search execution though if the searchview is null that is the issue I see at the moment. Is there some more global search event.

Comment: I have no idea of your project composition.  The above is meerly for you to try and get a reference to `_searchView` that I'm suspecting is null and is why your having issues.  If your able to package up something I can be more exact with the reason of the issue your experiencing.  Without so, I'm just guessing at what may be a fault your experiencing.  Sometimes its far quicker and easier to look at code.